# Can I use my Pebble to interact with Belkin Wemo devices?

Tags: pebble, wemo

My house makes heavy use of Belkin Wemo switches and bulbs. I would like to be able use my Pebble to turn on a number of devices.

[image: Pebbles]

There are apps that will integrate with Wemo, but they require a computer to be running on my local network, eg. "The WeMote app requires the Ouimeaux REST API running on a computer on the network to be able to work". I don't want to have to have a computer running 24/7.

[image: Wemo Light Bulbs]

Other than running a computer 24/7 how can I get my Pebble to talk to my Wemos?

Comment: Sad, Wemo killed their SDK: http://developers.belkin.com/wemo/sdk

Comment: And Pebble are dead as of today :(  https://blog.getpebble.com/2016/12/07/fitbit/

Answer (score 7):

**Raspberry Pi to the rescue**

Even though Wemo killed their SDK and Pebble is shutting down support as the question comments suggest the question is no less valid. Even more so, since the official support will fall through.

Since you need some device to run that API and you don't want to let your PC running, we'll have to look for a simpler device to run that API. One solution is to use a Raspberry Pi on which the REST API can be run. [This blog post](http://www.jenovarain.com/2016/05/install-ouimeaux-on-raspberry-pi/) details the few steps that are necessary to install the Ouimeaux server (which includes the REST API). It's two install commands, opening a few ports and you're done.

The commands that the server provides in the command line interface that the Pebble actually triggers can be found in the [wemo documentation](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/ouimeaux/latest/ouimeaux.pdf) on page seven.